# php client server on web host cant bind

Tags: php, sockets, web

I want to Run a simple Client-Server socket PHP script on my web host.
But i don't know how to exactly specify IP address and port number to work.

I test then on my wammp with success, but wen i upload them on my host control panel and run, they are not works.

***Here is my codes:***

**Client**

```
<?php
$host    = "105.24.123.188";
$port    = 8080;
$message = "hello";
echo "Message To server: ".$message. "<br>";
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// connect to server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
// send string to server
echo "After connect: ".$result. "<br>";
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
// get server response
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "Reply From Server: ".$result. "<br>";
// close socket
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

**Server**

```
<?php

$host = "105.24.123.188";
$port = 8080;
// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");

if (!socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
    exit;
} 
//echo "reached \n";
printf("this1\n");

// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket,  $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
///echo "reached \n";
printf("this2\n");
// accept incoming connections
// spawn another socket to handle communication
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
// read client input
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
// clean up input string
$input = trim($input);
echo "Client Message: ".$input. "<br>";
// reverse client input and send back
$output = strtoupper($input) . "\n";

socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
// close sockets
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

> [Error]

***Client***
Message To server: hello
After connect: 1
Reply From Server: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

***Server***

can't bind

I cant find out how to run  my simple example on web server.
IP address and port checked they are valid and open.

I test this on local host under wammp server in windows successfully but how i can put them in online real web?

> ***[?]***

Is anyone face this issue when Run client, server scripts in web host?

Can you guys show me some working example similar.

***How to obtain valid IP, Port to test them?***
I get these ip from run `ping www.myhost.com` on windows, is it true?

Comment: Clue: `0` is not an address.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone   I change it after reading a comment on php.org. now back to original version

Comment: Did you try to run it on different port? I'm running it right now and it's completely OK on my side.

Comment: Yes i check it, but no success.

Comment: I want to know how to run these code on my web server, i exactly not sure how to assign ip and port in client and server scripts

Comment: So both of these scripts are on the web server?

Comment: Yes: client in `www.some.com/test/client.php` and `www.some.com/test/server.php`

Comment: client return bad request, server returns not bind

Comment: Is there's any additional information to the bind operation or is it just **Could not bind to socket?**

Comment: It seems port `8080` is already in use on your server. So your server script cannot bind, and your client script connects to something else, which returns HTTP 400. If you can, just try another port. 8080 is a widely used port, e.g. Tomcat.

Comment: this1
Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in

Comment: Yeah that's what @KarstenKoop is talking about. Try to use something like `9005`.

Comment: 80, 8443, 8080, 443 are open ports on my ip address

Comment: Is i must set ip, ports same in client, server

Comment: Can anyone test these scripts on real host?

Comment: Yes, they must be the same. The ports you've posted are **not** recommended to use, because they're use by the **system**.

Comment: @Azuloo I need these scripts to run, what is my way, is necessary to buy a new service? or i can use this host for that

Comment: @EsmaeelE You don't need a new server, just pick a port that isn't already in use, 13055 for example.

Comment: @Azuloo even 13055 not works

Comment: What error message are you getting now?

Comment: similar its throw cant bind address in use